# rails url link helper methods undefined using full engines

Tags: routes, helper, rails-engines

Rails 3.2.12  2/27/2013

We have a full rails engine called **base2_cms** with a model called "**Event**". There is no issue on running the engine using rails server.

Next, another full rails engine called **base2_cvb** using **base2_cms** packaged as a gem.No issue in this.

Next, an application uses both of these engines as gems. We have been doing this since engines first came out, but have recently made a lot of changes. Somewhere along the line, routing stopped working. Or I guess more accurately, the rails url link helper methods.

At the application level, when using link_to with the second parameter as an instance of an event, this error occurs:

```
undefined method `event_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f82d52b3c20>:0x007f82d52a7240>
```

stack trace:

```
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb:129:in `polymorphic_url'

actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb:135:in `polymorphic_path'

actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb:111:in `url_for'

actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb:242:in `link_to'

base2_cms (0.9.40) app/helpers/application_helper_fieldset.rb:31:in `fieldset_combined_title'

base2_cms (0.9.40) app/helpers/application_helper_index.rb:35:in `index_start'

base2_cms (0.9.40) app/views/organizations/index.html.erb:2:in
```

This is not specifically polymorphic related, as we have other similar problems, such as getting this error in a different circumstance:

```
In order to use #url_for, you must include routing helpers explicitly. For instance, `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

We have tried following this last advice in various ways without success among many other attempted solutions.

Running rake routes at the application level returns the following concerning the events model:

```
GET    /events/:id/copy(.:format)                 events#copy
DELETE /events/:id/remove_organization(.:format)  events#remove_organization
POST   /events/:id/add_organization(.:format)     events#add_organization
GET    /events(.:format)                          events#index
POST   /events(.:format)                          events#create
GET    /events/new(.:format)                      events#new
GET    /events/:id/edit(.:format)                 events#edit
GET    /events/:id(.:format)                      events#show
PUT    /events/:id(.:format)                      events#update
DELETE /events/:id(.:format)                      events#destroy
```

Using the rails console at the final application level, we can even do this:

```
1.9.2-p320 :011 > app.event_path(9)
 => "/events/9" 
1.9.2-p320 :012 > app.event_path(Event.find(88))
  Event Load (13.1ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1      [["id", 88]]
 => "/events/88"
```

But, when using link_to in a view, it is unable to find the event_path method as described at the top.

Comment: Do your gems have an Isolated Namespace? How are you Engine routes mounted (both base2_cms with base2_cvb and base2_cvb with MainApp)? This may help, http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html#label-Using+Engine%27s+routes+outside+Engine

Comment: try `main_app.event_path` in your views

Answer (score 2):

When you're using engines, you have to specify if the route is of the main app or of an engine, if it's from main application you can do this with

```
main_app.event_path
```

if it's from base2_cms engine you can put

```
base2_cms.event_path
```

or if it's of base2_cvb engine:

```
base2_cvb.event_path
```

if you don't specify of where the route is it'll search the route for the current engine or from the main app if you aren't in any engine